# Programmatically launch VSTO Add-In with admin rights

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto, uac

We have a VSTO add-in installed per machine. Our application, that runs with limited permission launches Excel and programatically enables the VSTO addin.

The problem here is if `UAC` is turned On we receive the below error:

> "This addin is installed for all users on this computer and can only
>   be connected or disconnected by an administrator."

But i don't receive any error when `UAC` is turned off. So i understand that this is something  to do with `UAC` and i cannot force the user to run my application as an administrator.

Is there anyway to launch Excel using `InterOp` with administrative rights?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the manifest of this addin ? In the manifest-file i usually set "admin required" when that is the case. Then the uac-prompt appears properly.

Comment: Even after changing the manifest i get the same error message.

Comment: Do you receive an uac-popup ?

Comment: No, i don't get uac-popup.

Comment: A dirty workaround until you figured out why the manifest-setting is not accepted can be that you have another process let excel run as admin, for example you can create a shortcut and let excel run as admin using the compatibility-troubleshooter. Or use a tiny .net-app (set the manifest there properly) to start excel